# Grouping python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Could you tell me how to group a table (from products1.txt file) like following:

```
Age;Name;Country
10;Valentyn;Ukraine
12;Igor;Russia
12;Valentyn;
10;Valentyn;Russia
```

So I can find out how many Valentyns have an empty "Country" cell.
I ran the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('d:\products1.txt', sep = ";")
result = df[(df["Name"] == "Valentyn") & (df["Country"] == None)]
```

But I get an error...

Answer (score 2):

You should use `isnull` (rather than `== None`) to check for `NaN`:

```
In [11]: df[(df.Country.isnull()) & (df.Name == 'Valentyn')]
Out[11]:
   Age      Name Country
2   12  Valentyn     NaN
```

Another option would be to check those which had Country `NaN` and then count the values:

```
In [12]: df.Name[df.Country.isnull()]
Out[12]:
2    Valentyn
Name: Name, dtype: object

In [13]: df.Name[df.Country.isnull()].value_counts()
Out[13]:
Valentyn    1
dtype: int64
```